# Show that the following function is continuous on the set of real numbers: $f(x)=\sum _{\ n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{x^n}{n!})^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I think that I will have to use the ratio test, but I am not too sure.

Comment: Since we have sum of $(x^n/n!)^2$'s, and exponential function is continuous, it is enough to conclude that the sum of exponentials is continuous (unless you include the level of math and method required for this problem)

Comment: @NasuSama I don't think that ends up working; while you'll the $(x^2)^n$ in the numerator, you have $n!\cdot n!$, so I don't think it can be reduced to an exponential function.

Comment: Ah.  Thanks for the note.  I have some intuition for this problem.  This is why I include the note/comment.

Comment: For what it's worth $$\forall x\in \mathbb R\left[\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\left(\dfrac {x^n}{n!}\right)^2\right)=\dfrac 1{2\pi}\int \limits_0^{2\pi}e^{2x\cos (\theta)}\mathrm d\theta\right].$$

Comment: ... also known as $I_0(2x)$, where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind and order $0$.

Answer (score 6):

Fix a bound $M$ and consider the closed interval $[-M, M]$. Note that $$\left|\left(\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)^2\right| \le \frac{M^{2n}}{(n!)^2}$$

So we study convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{M^{2n}}{(n!)^2}$$

If it converges, the Weierstrass $M$-test gives that the desired summation is continuous. Note that after some algebra,

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{M^{2(n + 1)}}{((n + 1)!)^2} \cdot \frac{(n!)^2}{M^{2n}} &= M \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{(n + 1)!}\right)^2 \\
&= M \left( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 {n + 1}\right)^2 \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Can you put this all together?

Answer (score 4):

If you write it as $\sum_n \frac{(x^2)^n}{n!^2}$ you can see that it's a power series in $x^2$. A power series is continuous in every open interval where it *converges* (*), so all we need to show is that the series converges everywhere.

But that is easy -- each term is positive and less than the corresponding term in the power series for $e^{x^2}$ by a factor of $n!$, so it converges by the comparison test.

(*) I'm not sure if this fact counts as real analysis -- I think it's usually taught as part of complex analysis, but it's equally true on the real line.